# Why isn't possible to save revisions of the form design as draft?

Tags: webforms, 9

Apologies if this is repeating a previous post.

I have been using the webform module for a few years, mainly creating and managing web forms for clients.

The situation I have encountered with webforms, which is a feature available in other web-based form applications, is the ability to edit a form (add, edit and delete fields etc...) and then save a draft of the edited form instance, all while the live instance is still available for the public to complete. Practically, this can allow a client to test the draft instance of a form, and then publish once the client has reviewed the changes.

Although web forms can be closed to make changes, many clients require the form to remain available  24/7, so the idea would be to allow a backend user to edit and create a draft while the live instance is still available.

Overall, I just wondered why webforms have not incorporated this feature, or could this potentially be a feature to request put forward?

Comment: Would you please clarify the Webform version?

Comment: It is 6.1.2, running on Drupal 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature exists in the [config entity revisions](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_entity_revisions) module. There is an [experimental module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_revision_ui) which takes a different approach.

Comment: Wow, this is great! Exactly what I was looking for all this time. Appreciate the help!